# Views: show a list of users-profile who have multiple taxonomy terms?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, user-profile, drupal-taxonomy

I'm trying to set up a contextual filter that creates a list of profiles who have all the taxonomy terms the user choose.

I understand that there is no contextual filter like *"User: has taxonomy term"*, only *"Content: has taxonomy term"*.

There are some ways to set up a list of users based only on one taxonomy term using the term in the URL but I have no idea when it comes to multiple taxonomy terms.

For example:

1) During the registration, the user chooses 3 terms which will be associated with his account.

"What do you like?"

**Vocabulary1 :** Fruit --> *Apple*

**Vocabulary2** : Cars --> *BMW*

**Vocabulary3** : Sports --> *Schools*

2) In a view, the user can look for users who like **ALL** the selected items thanks to a contextual filter.

I hope this is clear, any inputs are welcome!

Comment: Do you need to do it with a View or are you opened to other suggestions (manual query)?

Comment: Well, since I'm not familiar with coding I tought about Views but I'm open to other suggestions as I don't see how Views can do that

Comment: Have you tried relationships (advanced) to do this?

Comment: Hi, I tried but I could only manage one taxonomy term per user I have to admit. Do you have an idea about this?